# UITableViewCells not appearing in second Tab

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitabbar

I have the following problem:
I am making a Pokédex-like application that displays a list of all 721 Pokémon on the first tab, and another list on the second tab containing My Favorite Pokémon. Essentially, there are two identical ViewControllers connected to my TabBar.

My storyboard is as follows:
[image: Storyboard]

**So here is the problem:**
The TableView on the first (and initial) tab works fine. However, when I load the TableView on the second tab the Pokémon are loaded, but not displayed. *I am able to click the TableViewCell and go to the detail page, but the label in the TableViewCell is not showing anything.*

[image: Favorites View]
[image: Pokédex View]

**This is the code I use for loading Favorites TableView**

```
class FavoritesViewController: BaseViewController,
UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet var FavoritesListView: UITableView!

var pokemonList: [String] = ["Nothing Here!"]



func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("FavoriteCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! FavoriteCell

    var name = pokemonList[indexPath.row]

    capitalizeFirstLetter(&name)

    cell.nameLabel.text = name

    return cell;
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return pokemonList.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    print(pokemonList[indexPath.row])

    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("ToPokemonDetail", sender: pokemonList[indexPath.row])
}




override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if(segue.identifier == "ToPokemonDetail"){
        let destination = segue.destinationViewController as! PokemonDetailViewController
        let thisPokemon = sender as! String

        destination.currentPokemon = thisPokemon
    }
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    FavoritesListView.reloadData()
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Fetch the cached list, getNames returns an array of strings
    let list = utility.getNames("Favorites")

    pokemonList = list

}
```

The delegate and the dataSource are set via the storyboard.

The above code works, and shows the Favorites list just fine. The class for the complete Pokédex has a similar construction.

I have tried switching Favorites and Pokédex around, so that it shows the complete Pokémon list on startup. All 721 Pokémon are shown correctly, but then the Favorites are not visible.

What else I have tried:

- Checking the Reuse Identifiers, over and over
- Referencing outlets should be bound correctly
- Calling TableView.reloadData() in the viewDidAppear method
- Switching around the tab items

Does anyone have any clue what on earth is going on here?
Feel free to ask any more questions

**Edit:** this is what happens when I swap the two TabBar Buttons around, no code changes

- [Pokédex Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aE45P.png)
- [Favorites Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0kyu.png)

[GitHub Project Here](https://github.com/DnJealt/MBD2-iOS/)

Comment: Is your cell for row at IndexPath being called or are the delegates connected ?

Comment: can you show the code behind this?

Comment: From where and when are you fetching your Fav? It should get the data before reloading the table.

Comment: I've updated my question, added the code behind the TableViews

Comment: In cellForRowAtIndexPath, check 'var name' value

Comment: not enough code here to diagnose.  Put the project on github and provide a link

Comment: @SteveRosenberg Done, link is in the bottom of the question

Comment: There is no tab bar in your git hub code

Answer (score 3):

Problem is in storyboard cell label frame. Set constraints of view controller for (Any,Any) Size Class. I can commit the code on github if you can give me write rights on your git. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your table's delegate and dataSource are not set.

```
table.delegate = self
table.dataSource = self
```

Of course this is after you add the properties to your view controller

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
```

Comment: The delegate and the dataSource are set via the storyboard. Please take a look at my updated question. I've added the code behind one of the TableViewControllers

Comment: Oh sorry. I will leave my answer posted in case it helps anyone else.

Answer (score 0):

Your number of rows is always 0 for that controller,
I looked into your code pokemonList count is always 0 its not updating data in it

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return pokemonList.count
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The big issue is your PokemonDetailViewController is not a UITableViewController.  It needs to inherent from UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate and then be connected to the storyboard view to provide data and formatting for a table.